# Google plus integration via Social Auth in Android?

Tags: android, google-plus

I am working on an app where I have to integrate Google Plus for Login purpose in the app.

Created an application on Google Console for Android and provide the Client Id and Client secret.

```
      try {

  adapter.addConfig(Provider.GOOGLEPLUS, "0000000000000000apps.googleusercontent.com", "00000000000", null);

    } catch (Exception e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    adapter.addCallBack(Provider.GOOGLEPLUS, "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");


    adapter.authorize(MainScreen.this, providers[3]);
```

The problem I am getting after allowing all the permission. On next screen a message "Please copy the code and switch to your application" is displayed.

[image]

I have searched alot regarding the problem and message. All I get is that the mistake is related to WRONG PROJECT TYPE selection while creating project on Google Console. But, in my case I have registered for the application correctly and selected Android as technology while configuring my project on Console.

Please suggest.

Comment: have u update play store lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that can be due to WRONG PROJECT TYPE Make sure while Creating New Client ID, choose Web Application and enter you callbackurl and domain name. This link might help you more https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth-android/wiki/Guide-Google-Plus

Comment: Thanks Avani, that was an awesome answer for me.